# TP-Link Archer T2U - AC600 network adapter driver installation on Fedora 27

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, dkms

I have this network usb adapter. I cloned repo and installed it with `make&make install` from [https://github.com/nlkguy/archer-t2u-plus-linux][1]

But It does not detected. Kernel version is **4.14**. When trying install with `sudo make dkms_install` it gives:

```
cp -r * /usr/src/8812au-
dkms add -m 8812au -v 
Error! Invalid number of arguments passed.
Usage: add <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module>/<module-version> or
       add -m <module> -v <module-version>
make: *** [Makefile:1789: dkms_install] Error 1
```

How can I make adapter detected?
[1]: https://github.com/nlkguy/archer-t2u-plus-linux

Comment: Fedora 27 has been unsupported for years. It's rife with vulnerabilities and issues.

Comment: Yes but are there any way to install it?

Comment: Sorry, that's too much to write, I'm lazy today.